# Performance Degradation After PC repair

Tags: windows-10, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, troubleshooting, laptop-repair

My PC is running at a horrible frame rate for all games. Everything took a huge hit after I replaced my motherboard. To give context the issue started very oddly I plugged in a Bluetooth speaker from Bose and for some weird reason it shorted my motherboard and thus my PC wouldn't boot or turn on at all.

So instead of paying Razer basically a new laptop, I purchased an OEM motherboard for the same model and same specs (Yes I am 1,000% percent sure it's OEM and not a third party) and installed it.

My computer runs completely fine in a Windows environment with general tasks or even my general workload but once I decide I want to play some games my framerate tanks extremely hard. At first, I thought it was just online games due to poor connection but I attempted multiple Single-player games and they all ran horribly even very old games didn't run right it just couldn't handle anything from 2016 and up.

I haven't tried even older games like Warcraft 3 or anything like that. Of course, I tried playing with the settings which did nothing, I updated every single driver I could do especially the GPU being a Nvidia 3080.

Still, nothing worked.

I even went into the BIOS to force the PC to only utilize the discrete GPU which still didn't do anything. I played with the battery options to force maximum performance, I ran scans on my SSD to no avail. I also made the same attempt within Nvidia to force only discrete GPU but still, the frames are so low. Also, one more thing to note I did reseat everything clean everything, and repasted the thermal paste on the CPU and GPU. Are there any ideas on what I should do with this extremely odd issue?

Specs:

- **Model**: Razer Blade 15 Advanced mid-2021 Model
- **GPU**: Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080
- Windows 10 Home (latest updates)
- 32 GB Ram
- 2 TB of NVMe SSD Storage
- **Processor**: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz, 2304 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processors

Comment: Have you asked the board seller if you can return for an equal board?   Did you reinstall Windows (new board) and if not consider doing that.

Comment: I think you have damaged other components that you are not aware of - in your BIOS you may be able to run tests on the hardware to confirm the functionality, there are also other tools in windows which can test hardware such as winsat

Comment: Have you tried running benchmarks on your CPU, GPU, and SSD individually? For free benchmark programs, CPU-Z has built-in benchmark, CrystalDiskMark can mark your SSD, and FurMark can be used to benchmark your GPU (though it puts quite some stress). You can then compare your results with values of hardware same as yours online.